# jQueryUI 1.12.1 invisible tick on CheckboxRadio widget

Tags: jquery-ui, checkboxradio

Using a "dark" theme such as UI Darkness, Le Frog or Dark Hive with jQueryUI 1.12.1, the new [CheckboxRadio](http://jqueryui.com/checkboxradio/) widget has an invisible white-on-white tick.  You can see this on [Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/). The problem occurs because the tick follows the "Clickable: default state > icon" colour while the tickbox background is "Clickable: active state > text", and dark backgrounds usually set both these things to a light colour.

The tick would be visible if it was in the "Clickable: active state > icon" colour which, IMHO, is what the designers intended.  However, the CSS rule precedence isn't quite right - it is for active buttons, but not for active non-buttons that are using "ui-button" styling.

A demo of the fault and my proposed fix is available on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmbro/yo2991ut/).  Essentially they need to add this:

```
.ui-button.ui-state-active .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png");
}
```

though my demo has the absolute path.

I hope this post saves you some head-scratching as to why your CheckboxRadio isn't working the way you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I've reported the problem on the jQueryUI bug tracker ([#15155](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/15155)), though at the time of writing they haven't picked it up.  Is this the right place for "theme" issues?